# Create a Listview with sections

Tags: android, uitableview, listview, user-interface

Hello guys i wanna make an interface that looks something like a Listview with an Spinner. For example imagine i have listview that contains Section 1, Section 2 and Section 3, when i click Section 1 above i want to be displayed Section 1.2, Section 1.2 and Section 2 and Section 3 scroll down

Section 1

Section 2

Section 3

If i click Section 1 i want the interface looks like this

Section 1

```
    Section 1.2

    Section 1.2
```

Section 2

Section 3

if anyone have an idea would be great help to me. Thank You.

Comment: You can use `ExpandableListView` with `SimpleExpandableListAdapter` or `BaseExpandableListAdapter`

Answer (score 0):

To use a List with sections you have to use ExpandableListView.
Refer Link [**ExpandableListView**](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html)

For working demo of this ExpandableListView refer this link [**ExpandableListView Demo**](http://androidtrainningcenter.blogspot.in/2012/07/android-expandable-listview-simple.html).